# -ms-user-select css property not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to enable selection/highlighting of a text that has been disabled by default in IE11. I'm using this prop to turn on the selection:

```
-ms-user-select: text;
```

i also tried the following values:

```
-ms-user-select: element;
-ms-user-select: auto;
```

nothing works for me.Any clue what would be the alternatives to enable selection?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just plain `user-select` in IE 11?

Comment: yes..it says invalid property and underlines red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-ms-user-select: contain; /*IE,Edge*/
-webkit-user-select: text; /*Webkit*/
-moz-user-select: text; /*Mozilla*/
user-select: all; /*Global, select all with one click*/
```

This worked for me.  I used IE Reference at  and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select .. Note: element has changed to contain!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `!important`

```
-ms-user-select: text !important;
```

Comment: If you would like to use javascript you can try that code:  (https://jsfiddle.net/gem87xmq/)